# Mongoose connection taking time

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Mongoose connection is taking more than 10s everytime. URI is that of MongoDB Atlas, Free Cluster.

```
console.log("Start time", new Date());
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, (err) => {
    if (err) return console.log("DB not connected: ", err);
    return console.log("DB Connected \nEnd time", new Date());
});
```

[image: Timestamp]